# Laravel Eloquent and Trimming fields for use in relationships

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, trim, relationships

So I've got a couple of models which I'm setting up for use with Laravels Eloquent ORM...

The tables these models refer to are populated by a third party program, which I do not have much ability to edit, so the following annoyance I have to find a work-around for.

The users tables have string IDs, example: `1234`

Some other tables (action logs for example) have a string foreign user ids, example: `"1234"`

As you can probably see here, the other tables add a `"` onto the user IDs, and as such, I can't run it straight through a laravel relationship, as `"1234"` ~= `1234`...

So I'm trying to find out if there is some way I can run the `"1234"` through a trim function or similar to remove the `"`s before it gets used in the eloquent relationship.

And yes, I know it's silly to add `"`, as mentioned, it's a third party program. I'm going to try to see if they can change that functionality, but in the case they cannot, I need to find a way to work around it.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Example of the relationship code:

```
public function useractions(){
    return $this->hasMany('\App\UserActions','userid');
}



public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\User','userid');
}
```

This is a crosspost from: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-and-trimming-relation-fields

Comment: unfortunately, I don't believe it's that simple. I've edited the post with an example snippet of code for a relationship in laravel. There is no retrieval of the id column data for the relationship, only a reference to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Eloquent Raw expressions.

```
public function useractions(){
    return \App\UserActions::Where(DB::raw("TRIM(userid)"), $this->userid)->get();
}
```

Comment: this doesn't returns a HasMany instance but a Collection